# Log in Twitter swift

Tags: swift, twitter, authentication, oauth, twitter-login

I need log in to Twitter without using the IOS Twitter login. I've been trying to use request and [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift), but am not having success. I think it's 
I have only been able to do it using the IOS Twitter login.

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
            let composer = TWTRComposer()
            composer.setText("Enviado usando o aplicativo Selfie Top")
            composer.setImage(self.imageFiltered)
            composer.showFromViewController(self) { result in
                if (result == TWTRComposerResult.Cancelled) {
                    print("Tweet composition cancelled")
                }
                else {
                    let messageVC:MessageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("message") as! MessageViewController
                    messageVC.completed = {()->Void in
                        self.present?.counterTwitter = (self.present?.counterTwitter?.integerValue)! + 1
                        try! self.moc?.save()
                        self.startCamera()
                    }

                     Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.logOutUserID((session?.userID)!)
                     Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.reloadSessionStore()
                    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print("Sending tweet!")

                }
            }

        } else {
            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
```

Comment: Have you integrated fabric and twitterKit?